# Airflow unpause dag during manual trigger

Tags: airflow-2.x, airflow-api

I am using Airflow 2.2.2 and have a dag which is scheduled to run every 10 minutes and is paused. I am trying to invoke it manually using airflow client. Dag is not getting unpaused and dagrun is in queued stated. Is it possible to unpause dag using airflow client when creating dag run without invoking additional API call.

```
        api_instance = dag_run_api.DAGRunApi(api_client)
        dag_run = DAGRun(
            logical_date=datetime.now(timezone(timedelta())),
            conf=request_data,
        )
        api_response = api_instance.post_dag_run(
            "airflow_testn", dag_run
        )
```

Comment: Even I am looking for its answer, Currently I have to use patch dag api to first unpause it and then another api to trigger it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the parameter *is_paused_upon_creation = False* to your default_args

(Optional[bool]) -- Specifies if the dag is paused when created for the first time. If the dag exists already, this flag will be ignored. If this optional parameter is not specified, the global config setting will be used.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).